# Fx.Slide SlideIn effect after domReady (mootools)

Tags: javascript, mootools

anyone knows what could be wrong with that javascript code?
it is executed, but the slidein animation is not shown

I'm using mootools 1.2.4

- mootools-1.2.4-core.js
- mootools-1.2.4.4-more.js

my first try:

```
   window.addEvent('domready', function () {
        var mySlide = new Fx.Slide('errorBox');
        var ie = /MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent);

        if ((ie && document.getElementById("errorBox").innerText == "") || !ie && document.getElementById("errorBox").textContent.trim() == "") {
            mySlide.hide();
        }
        else if (!ie && document.getElementById("errorBox").textContent.trim() == "") {
            mySlide.hide();
        } else {
            mySlide.slideIn();
        }
    });
```

Adding the delay also don't help, after page is loeded the box appears without any delay or animation

```
    window.addEvent('domready', function () {
        var mySlide = new Fx.Slide('errorBox');
        var ie = /MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent);

        if ((ie && document.getElementById("errorBox").innerText == "") || !ie && document.getElementById("errorBox").textContent.trim() == "") {
            mySlide.hide();
        }
        else if (!ie && document.getElementById("errorBox").textContent.trim() == "") {
            mySlide.hide();
        } else {
            mySlide.slideIn().chain(function () {
            // Waits one second, then the Element appears without transition.
                this.slideIn.delay(5000, this);
            });
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you see? Does `#errorBox` just hide immediately without animation? In that case, one of your earlier conditions may have been triggered, bypassing the `else`.

Comment: yes it just hides without animation, i will check it :D